# HTML5 Audio API stop a sound triggered with noteGrainOn

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is there a way to stop (or forever pause) a sound played with ..

```
audioSource.noteGrainOn(when, starthere, duration_sound);
```

..before the "duration_sound" variable stops it? Is it via NoteOff, but how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  (note that you should use .start() - noteOn() and noteGrainOn() are deprecated.)

Just call

```
audioSource.stop( 0 );
```

to stop immediately, or you can schedule a stop before the sound is finished playing by calling

```
audioSource.stop( whentostop );
```

Comment: I've been testing now and this works fine on Chrome. However on my mobile safari and desktop safari.. start() doesn't seem to work. Any info on the support for start() vs noteGrainOn()?